# Can we consistently add functions indexing universal equivalence relations to MK?

Tags: set-theory, first-order-logic

Starting with Morse-Kelley set theory $\sf MK$:

> Can we consistently make the following additions to $\sf MK$:

Add a primitive *total* unary function $F^\phi$ for every predicate symbol $\phi$ of the language (definable or primitive).

For convinience *elements* would be represented in lower case, while classes are represented in upper case. [the language is mono-sorted, so this is pseuo-sorting]. Add the following schema:

**Universal equivalence relations:** if $\phi$ is a predicate symbol, then:

$\phi \text{ is equivalence relation } \ \\ \forall A \forall x \exists B : \phi(A,B) \land x \in B \\ \implies \\\forall A  \exists k: k=F^\phi(A) \  \\ \forall A \forall B: F^\phi(A) = F^\phi(B) \iff \phi(A,B)  $

Comment: What is the motivation for considering such equivalence relations? Do you have an example in mind?

Comment: @Alex Kruchman, The cardinality function is an obvious example. Actually I was thinking of just a theory that have axioms of extensionality, class comprehension, and pairing, then we augment that base with those functions.